# Multiple colors in a UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, ios5

Given the following UITableViewCell code, how can we make `myObj.firstName` red and `myObj.lastName` green?

```
UITableViewCell *cell;
....
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", myObj.firstName, myObj.lastName];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to require two instances of `UILabel` to achieve this because `UILabel` doesn't support drawing instances of `NSAttributedString`. You could also subclass `UITableViewCell`, override `drawRect:` and draw the text manually with the required colors with the `-drawTextAtPoint:` methods on NSString.

Comment: The colors need to dynamically set depending on the data.  Is this still something that could work in a subclass?

Answer (score 1):

You could try setting the cell.textlabel to a OHAttributedLabel instance.

[OHAttributeLabel @ GitHub](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel)

Comment: This doesn't appear to work with ios5.  Many errors, even with adding the CoreText framework.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this may help others, I've solved this with...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomCell *cell = [tv dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    ...

    // Get the size of UILabel firstName.
    CGSize size = [[cell.firstName text] sizeWithFont:[cell.firstName font]];

    // Draw UILabel lastName next to UILabel firstName.
    // UILabel firstName was initialized in CustomCell.m in -(void)layoutSubviews.
    cell.lastName.frame = CGRectMake(size.width + 50, 23, 40, 15);

    // Make lastName green, oh yeah!
    cell.lastName.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0.6 blue:0 alpha:1];
}
```